# Is there a hook for when an AJAX call returns?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that you can add a listener to the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event so that you can run code when a new tab is opened or the url of a tab changes.

However I was wondering is there a similar event/hook you can listen to so that you can run code when an AJAX call returns?

I'm asking because I need to check a web page every 3 seconds to see if certain text has appeared through AJAX. So basically I have to poll the page. Obviously it would be more efficient if I didn't have to poll the page and if I could run the code only when AJAX calls return as that is when I need to do the scan.

So is there a hook/even for this or will I just have to stick to polling the page?

Comment: A callback function could be configured for the onreadystatechange handler to call.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [experimental webRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html), that allows you to hook into all HTTP requests made by the browser. Since it's experimental you'd have to enable the `--enable-experimental-extension-apis` flag in chrome://flags or on the command line

Comment: This feature is no longer experimental!

Answer (score 0):

That callback would be executed by the same javascript that called that ajax event. Its usually referred to as an ajax callback method.

In jQuery its:

```
$.ajax({method: "GET", url: 'some url' }).complete(function() { //do your function here });
```

in Mootools its:

```
new Request.JSON({ method: "GET", url: 'someurl', onComplete: function() { //do your function here });
```

In plain old javascript, you have to write in functionality for a custom callback into your XmlHttpRequest function as a function that executes when a certain ajax status code is reached

Comment: I am not looking to write AJAX functions. I want to 'listen' for AJAX calls so that I can scan the page for certain text once the AJAX call returns.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald my mistake, I misunderstood what you were asking